# selectable not working with jquery and jquery-mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-ui-selectable

I am trying to get selectable working with jquery and jquery-mobile.

I have it almost working in my code.   The problem I have is when I added this code to bind to the control key that it
slows down and does not work:

```
 $("#tableId").bind("mousedown", function (e) {
                         e.metaKey = true;
                  }).selectable();
```

I am working with an example in JsFiddle.  In JSFiddle I can get the example working (I had it working for a bit, but then 
it stopped working).

Could someome look at my jsFiddle code and let me know what I am doing wrong???

http://jsfiddle.net/bcsmith100/Y3TUj/32/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't had jQuery UI added as a external source.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

P.S In jsfiddle you should add the libraries using the external ressource tab to the right

Working [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Y3TUj/36/)

Comment: Thank you.    This was very helpful.    Now I can work on the bigger problem I have.   Your help is appreciated.